# Ruby on Railsのルーティングエラーに関して

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/"
と出てしまい詰まってしまいました。

処理内容。
トップページにform_forでベータ版のメールアドレスを登録する入力窓を置き、そこにメールアドレスを入れてsubmitするとデータベースに保存されるという単純な処理なのですが、ルーティングエラーで先に進めません。
以下コントローラー

```
class RootController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @guest = UserInvitationBetarelease.new
  end

  def create
    @guest = UserInvitationBetarelease.new(guest_params)
    @guest.save
    redirect_to root_index_path
  end

  private

  def guest_params
    params.require(:guest).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

- 以下View

  = form_for :guest do |f|
      = f.text_field :email
      = f.submit "送信"

ルートファイルは以下
`resouces :root`

教えていただければ幸いです

Answer (score 1):

POST / が定義されていないのに、そこにアクセスした為のエラーです。
下記の rake コマンドで、現在定義されているルートを確認することができます。
このコマンドの結果と、config/routes.rbの設定、formのaction属性を比べながら対応してはいかがでしょうか？

```
bin/rake routes
```

resources :root と指定した場合...

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :root
```

以下のような感じで、`/root`から定義されるはずです。

```
$ bin/rake routes
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
root_index GET    /root(.:format)          root#index
           POST   /root(.:format)          root#create
  new_root GET    /root/new(.:format)      root#new
 edit_root GET    /root/:id/edit(.:format) root#edit
      root GET    /root/:id(.:format)      root#show
           PATCH  /root/:id(.:format)      root#update
           PUT    /root/:id(.:format)      root#update
           DELETE /root/:id(.:format)      root#destroy
```

formタグのaction URL が間違っているのでは無いでしょうか？

それと、厳密には調べていませんが、rootというリソース名やコントローラ名は、予約語に該当してしまいそうで、あまり良くないかと思います。変更することをおすすめします。